# EmberJS How to create an option in a select menu from a controller property

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I'm building an ember application and want to create a select menu. One of the options for the select menu must be the total number of products in my data store.

I have created a property for the total number of products. How do I put this in the array I create my select menu from? Code as below:

**HTML snippet:**

```
{{view "select" content=itemsPerPageOptions}}
```

**Controller Code:**

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  totalItems: function(){
    return this.get('length');
  }.property('length'),

  itemsPerPageOptions : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, this.totalItems],
});
```

At the moment I get a blank value for the final option in the select menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a property depending on `totalItems` and use `get('totalItems')` because `totalItems` is also a property:

```
itemsPerPageOptions: function(){
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, this.get('totalItems')];
}.property('totalItems')
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse, perfect solution. Can you vote up my question for reputation?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think `this.totalItems` is available at the time that you are setting `itemsPerPageOptions`

Try this:

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  totalItems: function(){
    return this.get('length');
  }.property('length'),

  itemsPerPageOptions: [],
  init: function() {
    var tmpOptions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var newVal = this.totalItems();
    tmpOptions.push(newVal);
    this.set(`itemsPerPageOptions`,tmpOptions);
  }
});
```

I'm also not sure that `this.get('length')` is what you are looking for, I wouldn't expect that to return any value. You may be looking for `this.get('model.length')`.